# how to fetch only content from table by avoiding unwanted codes

Tags: python, mysql, django

I was trying to fetch text content from table which works well but along with result it print unwanted codes

my code is here

```
searchitem = searchme.objects.filter(face = after) .values_list ("tale" , flat = True)
```

the contents are text
the result I receive is "querySet Prabhakaran seachitem"
but I only want o get result "Prabhakaran"

model is this

```
 class searchme ( models.Model): 
      face = models.TextField()
      tale = models.TextField ()
```

Comment: Add your Model class and views.py

Comment: my models is   class searchme ( models.Model):
    face = models.TextField()
    tale = models.TextField ()

Comment: Try this searchme.objects.values_list('tale', flat=True).get(face=after)

Comment: user8193706 your suggestion worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official django documentation :

```
A common need is to get a specific field value of a certain model instance. To achieve that, use values_list() followed by a get() call:
```

So use:

```
searchme.objects.values_list('tale', flat=True).get(face=after)
```